# Placing 2 elements at same distance of table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, margin

I'm trying to put my 2 paginations at the same vertical distance of my table.

This works for the bottom part but the top part appears to be in my table-container for some reason.

CSS:

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    clear: both;
}
.table-container {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
section {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.pagination {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: I decided to both paginations and the table in a row now. You could just use inspect element and check the full code.

Comment: Please refrain from changing the code on your website or do as @Nick Bull said.

Comment: Pls be specific with your issue: What is the end result you want to achieve?

Comment: Edited post to make clear what the goal is.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the spacing issue, change

```
.pagination {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

to

```
.pagination {
  display:inline; //or block
}
```

You should also wrap your .pagination in a `.col-xs-12 .col-md-12` div like this. Always include the xs classes as Bootstrap is mobile first.

```
<div class="row>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
  <ul class="pagination">
    //code
  </ul>
   //rest of code
 </div>
</div>
```

Also, this

```
<section>
 <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2"></div>
 <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">
   //code
 </div>
</section>
```

should be

```
<section>
  <div class="row>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">
      //code
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

As the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro) state

> Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You have no margins on your rows. Other things are affecting it that are inside the rows. For example, you have a `<div class="pagination">` is `display:inline-block`. If you remove that, the bottom `5px` margin goes away.